# Getting the IEnumerable/List from different SQL tables with c# net-core

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, .net-core

I need to create C# code that returns a list of what product are bought together with others. The tables are in a SQL Server database.

I have this table:

| orderId | productId |
| --- | --- |
| A111 | 1 |
| A111 | 21 |
| A111 | 12 |
| A111 | 31 |
| A122 | 21 |
| A122 | 43 |
| A122 | 32 |
| A122 | 1 |
| A333 | 12 |
| A333 | 64 |
| A333 | 63 |
| A333 | 21 |
| A333 | 12 |

I also have this `Product` table:

| ProductId | ProductName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ProductName1 |
| 21 | ProductName21 |
| 12 | ProductName12 |
| 31 | ProductName31 |

And I want this result:

| productId | bought together with (productId) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 |
| 1 | 21 |
| 1 | 31 |
| 1 | 64 |
| 1 | 63 |
| 21 | 1 |
| 21 | 12 |
| 21 | 31 |
| 12 | 1 |
| 12 | 21 |
| 12 | 31 |
| and so on... |  |

It's kind of complex to do it in a C# .NET Core app...

Any ideas? Please

Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Don Juan,could you please share your model design?

Comment: I dont have any get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you use database first,you need firstly generate the models and DbContext.

Use `Scaffold-DbContext` to create a model based on your existing database. The following parameters can be specified with Scaffold-DbContext in Package Manager Console:

```
Scaffold-DbContext [-Connection] [-Provider] [-OutputDir] [-Context] [-Schemas>] [-Tables>] 
                    [-DataAnnotations] [-Force] [-Project] [-StartupProject] [<CommonParameters>]
```

In Visual Studio, select menu Tools -> NuGet Package Manger -> Package Manger Console and run the following command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=YourDatabaseName;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

`Server=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` refers to local SQLEXPRESS database server. `Database=YourDatabaseName;` specifies the database name "YourDatabaseName". `Trusted_Connection=True;` specifies the Windows authentication. It will use Windows credentials to connect to the SQL Server. The second parameter is the provider name. We use provider for the SQL Server, so it is `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`. The `-OutputDir` parameter specifies the directory where we want to generate all the classes which is the Models folder in this case.

After auto generate the models and DbContext,you could use DbContext to run linq to get the result you want:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly YourDbContext _context;
    public HomeController(YourDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Index()
    {
        var model = (from o in _context.Order
                    join p in _context.Order
                    on o.OrderId equals p.OrderId
                    where o.ProductId != p.ProductId
                    select  new { 
                         ProductId = o.ProductId,
                         BoughtWithProductID = p.ProductId
                    })
                    .OrderBy(a=>a.ProductId).Distinct().ToList();
    }
}
```